# Ruby Equivalent of the GD Library usage in PHP

Tags: ruby, gd

I am looking to write an app that overlays images and copy on top of another image. I know in PHP you can use the GD library but for Ruby does anyone have a specific suggestion of a gem that would help with this?

I have seen 2 gems already but not sure which is the one most people use.

https://github.com/Spakman/ruby-gd
http://rubygems.org/gems/gd2

Answer (score 3):

gd is a bit dated as a library for image manipulation/processing. The gems you listed are old, quite old in fact and likely will have issues with newer versions of Ruby.

Based on my own experience, I would look into a gem like [minimagick](http://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) which provides a nice interface to ImageMagick which is a more common library for the tasks you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The modern version of gem for working with GD library is https://github.com/dark-panda/gd2-ffij ... obviously, ImageMagick bindings are more powerful, but ImageMagick library have much more dependences and is generally heavyweight.

Comment: Just FYI, answers of this nature have a tendency to be marked as 'Link only' and deleted. I'd recommend fleshing it out a bit.